# How to go thru all database entries on android?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have the table and it has some number of rows there. Columns there are `KEY_ROWID` and `KEY_TITLE`. 
I need to go thru them one by one (except empty `KEY_TITLE` rows) and current cursor position is `KEY_ROWID = rowId`.

Just to illustrate the same:

```
KEY_ROWID    KEY_TITLE
  1           
  3           title3
  4           title4
  5           
  7           title7
```

rowId is equal to 4. User presses the button, we should get details of next row with non-empty title, i.e. row 7. User presses it again - we should get row 3 (starting from the start when end is reached).

How to implement the same?
Believe, I should get all rows where `KEY_TITLE` non-empty to Cursor. Then, there are methods like `moveToNext`, `moveToFirst`, `isLast`.
But how can I set current position? Do I need to go thru all rows first and compare rowIds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written the following code for the same:

```
/**
 * Get next record 
 * 
 * @param next possible values are +1 - move forward, -1 - move back
 * @return rowId of the next record
 */    
public long getNextRecord(int next, long rowId) {
    long nextRowId = 0;
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_TITLE}, KEY_TITLE + "!=\"\"", null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.i(TAG, "rowId/KEY_ROWID/KEY_TITLE: "+rowId+"/"+mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID))+"/"+mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_TITLE)));
            if (mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID)) == rowId) {
                if (!mCursor.move(next)) {
                    // first (-1) or last position
                    if (mCursor.getPosition() == -1) {
                        mCursor.moveToLast();
                    } else {
                        mCursor.moveToFirst();
                    }
                }
                nextRowId = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID));
                break;
            }
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
            mCursor.close();
        return nextRowId;
}
```

Is there any better/faster way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
 cursor.moveToPosition( int position); ?
```

Comment: Yes, but how to calculate the position?

Comment: perform a query : "WHERE KEY_TITLE IS NOT NULL" and you should then store the corresponding row ids in an array for example. then navigate thru it, if you reach the end of your array, just set the cursor back to the first row i suggest you have a look at this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#querying